# Creating a SQL Login for Windows user

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have a .Net application that connects to a SQL Server over the network. The user logs in as the Windows user. The SQL Server is set up as Windows Authentication only. From the client machine, the user is not created on the SQL Server as a login yet. On the first startup of the application, the application needs to check if the windows user is a sql server login and if not, the login must be created by the .net application.

My question is with which user do I log in to the SQL Server to check if the login exists. Obviously it cannot be the current windows user, as this user must be created first and on first run does not exist on sql server.

I already know how to proceed once a connection is established, and need help on the correct login to use when the windows user does not exist as a login on SQL server. Keep in mind that the server is set up for Windows Authentication only.

All of this must be done through .net code (vb or c#).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question, but answering it upon what I think you are asking:

You need to be logged in as the Administrator in Windows since you are using Windows Authentication Only. 
Once you have logged in as Admin, Windows will recognise that and give you all the authentication rights so when you go into your SQL server these rights will automatically be passed on, allowing your to create new user permissions and grant access etc...

Let me know if this answers your question correctly.

Comment: Scenario: I have sql server on PC 1 (call it sqlserver_pc1). I have the client app on PC 2 that connects to sqlserver_pc1. On PC 2 I have a user (pc2\user1) that has admin rights on PC 2. pc2\user1 logs on to PC 2 and starts the client app. pc2\user1 is not yet created as a login on sqlserver_pc1. When the client app starts, it must create the pc2\user1 login on sqlserver_pc1. Because pc2\user1 is logged in on PC 2, integrated security is not possible, as the login is not yet created. I want to know which user to use from PC 2 to connect to sqlserver_pc1 to be able to create pc2\user1.